# Algorithm to compute whether a stabbing line exists for a set of line segments

Tags: geometry, algorithms, computer-science, computational-geometry

Let $S$ be a set of $n$ segments in the plane. A line $L$ that intersects all segments of $S$ is called a traversal or stabber of $S$. Give a $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ algorithm to decide if a stabber for $S$ exists using duality.